# Angularjs contact form + PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, contact-form

I cannot seem to get working the contact form in Angularjs.  When I pres the button to submit, the submit function in the "Cnt_meCntl" controller is not firing.

HTML

```
<article>
    <form id="contact-form" nh-submit='submit()' method="post">
    <div>
    <label>
    <span>Name: (required)</span>
    <input placeholder="Please enter your name" type="text" ng-model="formData.name" required autofocus>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>
    <span>Email: (required)</span>
    <input placeholder="Please enter your email address" type="email" type="text" ng-model="formData.email" required>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>
    <span>Message: (required)</span>
    <textarea placeholder="Include all the details you can" ng-model="formData.message"  required></textarea>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</article>
```

controller.js

```
    ....when('/contact', {
        controller: 'Cnt_meCntl',
        templateUrl: '/content/Views/Contact.html'
   }).when('/resume', {
        controller: 'ResmeCntl',
        templateUrl: '/content/Views/Resume.html'
   })...
ospnWeb.controller('Cnt_meCntl', function($scope, $http){
    ...
    $scope.formData;
    $scope.submit = function () {
        console.log('Im in the controller');
        console.log($scope.formData);       
    }
});
```

Comment: Typo: `nh-submit` should be `ng-submit`

Comment: @Shomz thank you.  Now, I have another problem.  It cannot find the PHP which is in another folder. I tried the /folder/ and .../  , but nothing.